# Rename image name to datetime stamp

Tags: android, camera

How do i change the codes so that the image's name will be save as date time stamp?

```
Button buttonTakePicture;

    final int RESULT_SAVEIMAGE = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */   @Override   public
 void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_layout);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);         surfaceView =
 (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);        surfaceHolder =
 surfaceView.getHolder();       surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());        View
 viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_control, null);
        LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);        this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

        buttonTakePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takepicture);
        buttonTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, myPictureCallback_RAW,
                        myPictureCallback_JPG);             }       });

        LinearLayout layoutBackground = (LinearLayout)
 findViewById(R.id.background);
        layoutBackground.setOnClickListener(new
 LinearLayout.OnClickListener() {           public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                buttonTakePicture.setEnabled(false);
                camera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);          }       });     }

    AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback() {
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {            // TODO
 Auto-generated method stub             buttonTakePicture.setEnabled(true);         }
    };

    ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {         public
 void onShutter() {             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }   };

    PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {          // TODO
 Auto-generated method stub

        }   };

    PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {          // TODO
 Auto-generated method stub             /*
             * Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0,
             * arg0.length);
             */

            Uri uriTarget = getContentResolver().insert(
                    Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());           OutputStream imageFileOS;           try {
                imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriTarget);
                imageFileOS.write(arg0);
                imageFileOS.flush();
                imageFileOS.close();

                Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this,"Image saved: " + uriTarget.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();            }           camera.startPreview();      }   };

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int
 width,int height) {        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      if
 (previewing) {             camera.stopPreview();           previewing = false;         }

        if (camera != null) {           try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
                previewing = true;          } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();            }       }   }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {      // TODO
 Auto-generated method stub         camera = Camera.open();     }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {        // TODO
 Auto-generated method stub         camera.stopPreview();       camera.release();
        camera = null;      previewing = false;     }   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use Content Resolver to achieve it,

```
ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
v.put(Images.Media.TITLE, title);
v.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, System..currenttimemillis());
v.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, description);
v.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, dateTaken);
v.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, dateTaken);
v.put(Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED, dateTaken) ;
v.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, “image/jpeg”);
v.put(Images.Media.ORIENTATION, orientation);
```

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap, String retailerArray2) {

    long timeStamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

    String dateStamp = DateHelper.dateTime(timeStamp,
            "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm[:ss]");
File myDirectory = new File(root + "/ Gallery/" );
    if (!myDirectory.exists()) {
        myDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    String fname = Name + " -- " + dateStamp + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDirectory, fname);
}
```